# How to achieve that a sub-thread in multithreading ends first, and the primary thread continues to execute

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I try to implement a function: the primary thread creates multiple sub-threads and blocks the primary thread, and wakes up the primary thread to continue execution when any of the sub-threads ends.

The following code is my attempt to use std::future in C++11：

```
std::pair<size_t, size_t> fun(size_t i, size_t j)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(i * j));
    return { i, j };
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_future<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> ret;
    std::pair<size_t, size_t> temp;

    ret = std::async(std::launch::async, fun, 10, 9);
    ret = std::async(std::launch::async, fun, 5, 4);
    ret = std::async(std::launch::async, fun, 2, 1);
    temp = ret.get();
    std::cout << temp.first << "\t" << temp.second << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

For the result, I hope the program will directly output "2 1" after (2 * 1) seconds and end the primary thread, but in my attempt, the program needs to wait for the first sub-thread to sleep for (10 * 9) seconds before outputting "2 1" and end the primary thread.

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] inline in the question? Not as a picture which makes it very inconvenient to reproduce! Also, as a new user, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, there is one misconception you shouldn't fall for: Threads don't have parent/child relations. You're using slightly ambiguous wording there.

Comment: How you describe it, you'll need a condition variable which the main thread sleeps upon, and subthreads should signal it before exiting.

Answer (score 1):

You code has a few problems:

1. With the way you call `std::async`, you are not guaranteed to get any threads at all. You need to pass  `std::launch::async` as the first argument to achieve the effect you want. See the docs: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async
2. std::async returns a future, which you store in `ret`. But then in the next line, you overwrite the value in `ret`. That causes the future returned from your first thread to be destroyed. When futures returned from `std::async` are about to be destroyed, they block the current thread until they are completed. See the "Notes" section of the `std::async` docs.
3. What you are trying to achieve is unfortunately surprisingly difficult in c++ without any additional libraries. There is no simple way to say "wait until one of these threads is done". If you want to only use the STL, you have to use a "condition variable" to signal the main thread when the first of your subthreads is ready.

Comment: Sorry, I am a novice about multithreading. How to signal the main thread by "condition variable"? Could you please give me a demo or link to learn, thanks?

Comment: This tutorial shows a producer-consumer implementation: https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/13552/using-condition-variables. That also works with multiple producers, which would solve your issue.